# Nested For Loops not acting as expected

Tags: excel, vba

**Task:** I am trying to copy several cells in a row ( 13 at the moment) that may contain some blanks. I want to paste these values into 13 rows within a column.

**Attempts:** I have not had any luck with `.Pastespecial , Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:= True`.

**Current Approach:** I am trying to use FOR loops to validate and transfer.

```
Dim j As Long, I As Long
For j = 3 To 16
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then
  For i = 16 To 33
        oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value
    Next i
End If
Next j
```

**Problem:** However this code is taking the last nonblank cell from `Cells(aCell.Row, j).` and displaying it for all values of `i` in `oSht.Cells(i, 4)`.

**Request:** I am trying to determine what the error is with my FOR Loops or if there is an easier approach to copying several cells and pasting all nonblank cells.

Comment: Can you try doing `oSht.Range(oSht.Cells(16,4),oSht.Cells(33,4)).Value = Cells(aCell.Row,j).Value`? (Also, I highly recommend putting the other sheet name before `Cells(aCell.Row, ...` to be explicit which sheet that value is on.

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne , the suggestion did not produce any errors but it did not copy the text over either. In a previous post I discovered that defining the WB and WS for anything with `aCell` resulted in compiler errors. Correct me if I am wrong but since aCell is a defined cell the reference to the workbook and worksheet are already present.

Comment: Yes, but the `Cells(aCell.Row, j)` is not fully scoped. VBA would read that as `Cells(#, j)`, having defined what the row of aCell is but that does not cascade to the Cell reference. So its looking for a Cell but you haven't defined the Cell of what range so it will assume the Worksheet currently with focus. Might work if you aren't switching between sheets but not as rigorous as you could be.

Comment: I have added the worksheet reference. There doesn't appear to be an issue this time. I am looking into nesting `i = oSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row` within the first FOR loop and eliminating the second FOR loop. For some reason the worksheet is just staying blank as opposed to writing in the text.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the context is a bit difficult to provide a proper answer but I think the problem is the inner loop, it should be just a counter, like this:

```
Dim j As Long, I As Long
For j = 3 To 16
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then
  i=i+1
  oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value
End If
Next j
```

Comment: Thank you, I have considered that option. I can't seem to get the code to run past the first loop. Of the 16 lines to transfer only the first one does.

Comment: Would `i = oSht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row` not work also? I am not sure if there is an error with the code but in theory placing this where you have the counter should cause the program to check for the last row each iteration of the `for` statement.

Comment: yes, if i understood correctly you need to move the non-empty cells from one row into a column, so for every new j (column in the source row), if it is not empty, i (row in the destiny column) will move one down. Sorry if I misunderstood.